# How do I make my android app scale properly accross different devices?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, layout, scaling

I'm quite new to android development and I'm currently making an app for a nine men's morris game and I'm using a custom layout xml file with 1 image view for the game board and then 23 other image views for all the different points on the board, all inside a constraint layout and then I use the  tag to include this layout inside my main activity layout.

All the image views look perfectly aligned on a pixel 4 using the AVD but they dont look aligned when i test on older devices, so what do you guys think is the best way to make the image views align perfectly on all screen sizes? [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1unb.png) pic  shows how the layout looks and below i will post code for the first 4 image views

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/g_items">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/the_board"
    android:layout_width="376dp"
    android:layout_height="374dp"
    android:paddingEnd="15dp"
    android:paddingStart="15dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/board" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/point_0"
    android:onClick="onTileClicked"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/the_board"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/empty_spot"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/point_1"
    android:onClick="onTileClicked"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="104dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/point_0"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/the_board"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/empty_spot" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/point_2"
    android:onClick="onTileClicked"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="104dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/point_1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/the_board"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/empty_spot" />``
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use guideline widget with ConstraintLayout to tell your views when to stop when resizing(using app:layout_constraintGuide_percent  property).

[Google documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/Guideline)

Answer (score 0):

Set `width` and `height` of the `ImageView`s to `0`, this way the layout will use constraints instead of the absolute values.
Also add all constraints to each view (Start, Top, End, Bottom).